# How to return the result using AJAX in CodeIgniter?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I want to ask how to return the response like `return 'Password successfully updated';` or `return 'Failed to Update Record';` on my view using the AJAX. It's working fine before without AJAX after submitting it returning the response.

Now I just include the AJAX on my form the form is working fine. but the error and success message (response) not showing up after submitting.

Ajax

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.jsForm').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('change_password_process', $('form.jsForm').serialize(), function(data){
            $('div.response').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Model

```
public function updatePassword($data){ //update user password
    $oldPassword = $data['oldPassword'];
    $user = $data['user'];

    $this->db->select('password')
             ->from('users')
             ->where('username', $user);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $row = $query->row();

     if($this->bcrypt->check_password($oldPassword, $row->password)){
        if($this->db->set('password', $data['newPassword'])
                        ->where('username', $user)
                        ->update('users')){
            return 'Password successfully updated';
        } else {
            return 'Failed to Update Record';
        }

    } else {
        return 'Old password is incorrect!';
    }
}
```

Controller

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){

        $data = array(
                'user' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'oldPassword' => $this->input->post('oldPassword'),
                'newPassword' => $this->bcrypt->hash_password($this->input->post('newPassword')),
                'cPassword' => $this->input->post('cPassword')
        );

        //this is the response from MODEL 

     $this->session->set_flashdata('response',$this->user_accounts_model->updatePassword($data)); 
        //redirect('user_accounts/change_password_form');

    } else {
        $this->change_password_form();
    }
}
```

View

```
<?php if($response = $this->session->flashdata('response')) :?>

    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
      <?=$response?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?> //this is the form result w/out ajax

<div class="response"></div> //this is using ajax
```

Comment: where is your `change_password_process()` function.Please also post this function.In model try to `echo` instead of `return`.

Comment: ow yea haha I just Tried before looking on you answer.. Thankyou also.

Comment: any error on console.

Comment: There's no error :) I forgot i need to use echo instead of return hehe

Comment: oho then you solve it.Congrats

Comment: Thankyou.. I'm trying out ajax to improve my code :)

Comment: @Hekmat one thing I'm using form_error() its not going next to my input textbox now..

Comment: We don't use [solved] title devices here. I sometimes move people's answers merged incorrectly into questions into an answer below, but it seems that someone has already said the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In model just `echo` instead of `return`.

```
if($this->db->set('password', $data['newPassword'])
                        ->where('username', $user)
                        ->update('users')){
            echo 'Password successfully updated';
        } else {
            echo 'Failed to Update Record';
        }

    } else {
        echo 'Old password is incorrect!';
    }
```

Comment: <div class="container"> 
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Old Password</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
           <?=form_hidden('username', $user['username']);?>
            <?=form_password(['name'=>'oldPassword', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Old Password', 'autofocus'=>'autofocus']);?>
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6" align="left">
       <?=form_error('oldPassword');?>
      </div>
  </div>

Comment: beside my textbox

Comment: try using  `echo form_error('fieldName', '<div class="error">', '</div>')`;

Comment: its still going on the top of the page.

Comment: you can just use `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>` to display error.For more see here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: yeah im using that.. but using form_error. I can place the error message beside the textbox.

Comment: you have to send these error messages to view from controller when `$this->form_validation->run() == FALSE`.Did you send these messages in view?.